# Settings, GUI has been deleted and now cant connect to the internet

Tags: networking

I was trying to purge a few files on my system and accidentally deleted settings. The problem is that my system is a laptop and it isn't connected to the internet. I have tried connecting it to the broadband as well as through ethernet but it isn't working. (I.e. I can't download anything from the web). I have also tried switching the device on and off again to see whether network settings would come back but to no avail. The reason this cam about is because I was purging applications that were no longer required and I mustn't have seen that Ubuntu also included the Gnome-control-center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For info: Google "recovery mode".

In the very last moments of the "BIOS" text display,
hit ESC **once**.

... that should make the grub boot menu appear.

The "Advanced" option should show you a way into recovery mode.

Use the `fsck`, `network` options, then drop to a root shell prompt.

As you're there: Check whether a `apt update` works to begin with.
This might allow to do `apt install gnome-control-center`

Regardless; Please note: I cannot tell whether that would rectify all your problems though.

Answer (score 0):

Get a shell open with either `Ctrl, Alt and T` or `Alt F4` to open TTY.

Connect to wifi via `nmcli d wifi connect <ssid> password <pw>`

That should be the easiest method to get an uplink. Option two would be to create a `netplan` configuration.